# Why AWS Python SDK IAM Client get_account_authorization_details method producing Type Error?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I am using the code provided in the boto3 documentation (https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.get_account_authorization_details) and this code:

```
import boto3
import boto3.session

my_session = boto3.session.Session(profile_name='US-Prod')
client = my_session.client('iam')

response = client.get_account_authorization_details(
    Filter=[
        'User'|'Role'|'Group'|'LocalManagedPolicy'|'AWSManagedPolicy',
    ],
    MaxItems=123,
    Marker='string'
)
```

produces this error:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'
  File "C:\Users\bg216063\Documents\AWS\sre-scripts\excel\mkIAMxls.py", line 9, in <module>
    'User'|'Role'|'Group'|'LocalManagedPolicy'|'AWSManagedPolicy',
```

Why would these types not be supported when I have done a copy and paste from the documentation example?

Comment: The `|` is indicating that it's _at least one of those_ values. Try specifying `Filter=["User"]`, for example.

Answer (score 2):

The pipe symbol in the documentation means "or". In other words, you can specify `'User'` or `'Role'`, etc...

The documentation you linked also states:

> The format for this parameter is a comma-separated (if more than one)
> list of strings. Each string value in the list must be one of the
> valid values listed below.

To fix your code to be in line with the documentation (and to make it syntactically correct Python code), it would look like the following:

```
response = client.get_account_authorization_details(
    Filter=[
        'User','Role','Group','LocalManagedPolicy','AWSManagedPolicy'
    ],
    MaxItems=123,
    Marker='string'
)
```

Although at that point I think you can just remove the filter because you are requesting all types, so you aren't really filtering the results.